# Show that $ax+by=1 $ implies $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \leq a^2+b^2$

Tags: inequality

> Show that for real positive x,y,a and b: $ax+by=1 \implies \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \leq a^2+b^2$

I used to use contradiction but no results ;

We show that

$$a^2+b^2 < \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \implies ax+by \ne1$$

$$a^2+b^2 < \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \iff (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)<0 \iff (ax-by)^2-(ay-bx)^2 <0$$

I'm stuck here, I thought about proving it by putting something in a denominator which is not zero so it's not $1$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Use *Cauchy-Schwarz* inequality.

Comment: From OP's posting history, I am questioning whether they would be familiar with CS.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

For a nice geometric method, consider the circle $$x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}$$ and observe that any point on the line $$ax+by=1$$ is always *outside* of that circle, except for exactly one point.

Recall that the perpendicular distance of a point $(x_0,y_0)$ from a line $Ax+By+C=0$ is $$d=\frac{\left | Ax_0 + By_0 + C \right |}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

You may like to consider the distance of the line $ax+by=1$ from the origin, and you'll almost certainly observe that it has something to do with the circle I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Very instructive hint: +1

Comment: Then you mean here A=a ?

Comment: That is correct. Similarly $B=b$ and $C=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The magnitude of $(a+bi)(x+yi)$ is greater than the magnitude of the real part.